# How can I organize a network login with Swifts DispatchQueue() and completionHandlers?

Tags: dependencies, grand-central-dispatch, dispatch-queue

I'm trying to organize my login process with swifts DispatchQueue() and completionHandlers. First the user should log in and receive a jwt -token from the server, after that an automated download of a few things should happen.

I do have a function called `httpRequest(requestType:HTTPRequestType, parameter:Parameter = Parameter(), completionHandler: @escaping ((Result<Parameter?, HTTPRequestError>) -> Void) = { _ in })` that handles all my HTTP-Request.
If my requestType `.login` finishes with HTTP 200, it executes (within the `httpRequest`)

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
    let jsonObject = try? decodeParameter(data: data)
    self.httpToken = jsonObject?.httpToken
    self.sessionName = parameter.sessionName!
    }
```

On `.success()` of my `httpRequest()` the download of my data should start, unfortunately it sometimes does happen, that downloading starts too early - in face before that token is stored. This means no authentication which makes the server deny my request.
I did try a `queue = DispatchQueue("com.my.label", qos: .utility)` (which should be serial) and added

```
queue.async {
    // login
    httpRequest(requestType: .login) // with parameter, with or without completionHandler
    }
queue.async {
    // download
    httpRequest(requestType: .download)
    }
```

but this also gives me the same behavior.

same with `queue = OperationQueue()` with `queue.maxConcurrentOperationCount = 1` and obviously `queue.addOperation {}`

Any hints on how to solve this and make sure, that the login finishes and only THEN the downloads start? There are a few more downloads coming that depend on each other later on, this is just the first time it fails.

Answer (score 0):

The `httpRequest` is an asynchronous method, meaning that it starts the request and then returns immediately. So your various dispatch/operation queue approaches will make the problem far worse, as you’re starting the download immediately after initiating the login request, not waiting for the login request to complete.

You must use the completion handler:

```
httpRequest(requestType: .login) { result in
    switch result {
    case .failure:
        // handle error here
    case .success:
        httpRequest(requestType: .download)
    }
}
```

The virtue of this pattern is that you handle success and failure in different ways. E.g. if login failed, is there any point in trying all the downloads?

---

So, let us assume that you are correctly using the completion handler pattern, like above. If the problem persists, then the problem probably rests with a race associated with when you are setting the `httpToken`. E.g. you said:

> If my `requestType` `.login` finishes with HTTP 200, it executes (within the `httpRequest`)
>
> ```swift
> DispatchQueue.main.async {
>     let jsonObject = try? decodeParameter(data: data)
>     self.httpToken = jsonObject?.httpToken
>     self.sessionName = parameter.sessionName!
> }
> ```

What is notably absent here is the calling the completion handler. If you asynchronously dispatch the update of the token and session variables, but call the completion handler immediately, the completion handler could conceivably be called before these session properties are set.

So, you might want to move the calling of the `httpRequest` completion handler inside this dispatch to the main queue, after the setting of the session properties.

---

Not that it matters, but there are alternatives to the completion handler pattern. Other approaches include wrapping `httpRequest` in a custom, asynchronous, [`Operation`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/operation/) subclass that only sets `isFinished` when the request is done. Or [Combine](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/combine/). Or perhaps use the [async/await](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2021/10132/) patterns introduced Swift 5.5. There are other options, too. But, bottom line, you want to employ an asynchronous pattern which acts upon completion of the request, not just upon the initiation of the request.

Comment: the example you give is exactly what I was trying to do when I said: "On .success() of my httpRequest() the download of my data should start". Still somehow it starts the download too early and denies my the execution of the download (as I implemented a safety-method there that checks if the token has been set). Basically that's the main thing, why I was wondering.

Comment: Ah. The code snippet in your question is not using the login completion handler closure at all, and as such, it will make the problem far worse, starting the download immediately after initiating the login. But let's assume that you fix that and use the completion handler pattern. Then there is a second problem. I'm guessing that it could easily stem from the fact that you're asynchronously updating these session properties (but not the completion handler). See revised answer. But, in short, you haven't given us a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Following @Rob I rewrote my whole network tasks to async/await. Works pretty well now for everything that I can define as one function, like my "Login". I still struggle with everything where I have different user-actions triggering httprequests. Let's say my user logs in and automatically uploads his profile data. Now he goes to his profile and changes something - let's say his profession. this automatically triggers an upload to the server, which might finish before the profile data is uploaded. This would have an unexpected behavior, so I need to make sure to finish the first upload before.

Comment: Fine. So you would `try await` your network request and put the `dismiss`/`pop` on the next line of code. That way, the network request happens asynchronously and your dismiss/pop (or whatever) would take place when that request finishes and you confirm it was successful. It's the whole motivating idea behind `async`-`await` that you can write code that captures all of these dependencies between asynchronous tasks without all the hairly completion handler code.